# Property 'kendoGrid' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, webpack, angular-cli

I am using VSCode editor for my angular project development. VSCode intellisense is working fine with @typings/kendo-ui. But, Webpack compilation failed due to the error.

Error:

> "Property 'kendoGrid' does not exist on type 'JQuery"

[image]

This error is same for all kendo components

I am using latest angular CLI for this project.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you got the answer already, but kendoGrid is jQuery dependent. In addition to installing jQuery and the kendoGrid file, you should add your kendoGrid code in the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecyle hook in whatever component you are using like this :

```
  ngAfterViewInit(){
      $(document).ready(function(){
              // code to execute
              });
}
```

Also add `declare var $:any;` 
which declares the jQuery variable with any type. Assuming you added `import * as $ from 'jquery'` in your module file.

Comment: I have jquery typings in my project. So, I was getting duplicate $ declaration error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(<any>$("#grid")).kendoGrid()
```

Comment: I will loose the intellisense with the above code. Otherwise I would declare $ as separate constant like `declare const $: any` This also works. But, the thing is I want to have intellisense and be able to build the angular project